# Including modules, Is it right behavior?

Tags: ruby

[First case code](https://gist.github.com/1285611)
[Second case code](https://gist.github.com/1285615)
I was expecting to all methods from modules be included in both cases. Is it bug?

Comment: It's ok to include code snippets like this in the question.

Comment: It's not just "ok"; it's desired. Please do.

Answer (score 2):

Expected behavior. In the first example you are including `B` in `A` after you included it in `C`, so `A` doesn't have `B`s method when it gets included. In the second example you do it in the correct order.

Comment: I see it, in ruby I can define/redefine any methods in in any place, but when I include modules order is impotant. Now I have to keep order by including modules or use only one level of modules.

Comment: Yes, when including modules, order is important. Try to include several modules that define the same method and see which one "wins". BTW: if this is the answer you were looking for, please upvote/accept it, so others know.